Azure Data Factory (ADF) check in a dataflow that columns in dataset contains unique values (count rows per value)
I created a dataflow in which I need to check if the provided dataset (which contains many columns) has 2 columns which each should contain a unique value. I don't know the value in advance but I do know the names of the columns.
The whole point is to validate that these columns only contain unique values and if not, I want to fail the pipeline/dataflow.
Not planning to do anything with the output of this checks/validation.
I assume that I have to use an aggregate transformation together with some group_by but not entirely sure how:


Success scenario (validation/analysing data continues):


Failure scenario (dataflow/pipeline should fail):


Failure scenario (dataflow/pipeline should fail):


Failure scenario (dataflow/pipeline should fail):


Can you provide your sample input and expected output?

Hey Rakesh, The whole point is to validate that a column contains a unique value otherwise I want to fail the pipeline/data flow and send an e-mail. I dont want to do something specific with the output

Can you provide explain your scenario with a sample input and expected output for better understanding?

Do you know the column names in advance that you want to check whether unique or not?

Yes I do know the name of the columns that I want to check the values!

@RakeshGovindula I updated the questions with the needed information

As per your update, the pipeline should succeed if the two columns contains same value in all rows? if they don't, the pipeline should fail if there is not single value. Correct me if I am wrong.

You are correct. You can have an extra look of the csv screen shots


The whole point is to validate that a column contains a unique value otherwise I want to fail the pipeline/data flow and send an e-mail

Adding to @Potis23, after failing the dataflow you can use Alert rules in the ADF to send the mail for the activity failure.
Go to the Monitor -> Alerts and metrics -> create a new alert rule. Here, set the alert for the Dataflow activity failure instead of the pipeline failure.

Set all the configurations like Severity. In the criteria, select Failed activity runs metrics and give your activity name and pipeline name and kind of activity.

Next in the notifications, create action and give your mail id. By this way, you can send the mail on the dataflow activity failure. On the failure of the dataflow, you can go ahead with your other activities as per your requirement.

I just figured it out:

You need to take 3 steps

Connect the source with an Aggregate. You will find out all the unique values for this column



The output will look like this:


Connect the first Aggregate with another Aggregate. This will count how many unique value have been identified:



The output will look like this:


Connect an Assert with the second Aggregate. This will assert if the number of unique values for your column is 1. If not it will fail the dataflow:


The output will look like this:

If you have more than one columns that you need to check for the same datasource(csv), then create a new branch and repeat:


You can make your answer as accepted which might help the community who faces similar issue in future.

Sure I ll do that but need to w8 for 2 days as I answered my own question!
